# encoding/special chars at jquery TableExport plugin?

Tags: jquery, export-to-excel

i am using this plugin to export a html table:

[TableExport](https://github.com/clarketm/TableExport)

In the table there is a html coded char: Ö -> #ouml; in the word "Körper" in the Excel file it will create the word "K_rper".

This is my code:

```
<script>

var tableId = 'tab1';
var ExportButtons = document.getElementById(tableId);

var instance = new TableExport(ExportButtons, {
    formats: ['xls', 'csv'],
    exportButtons: false
});
// **** jQuery **************************
//    $(ExportButtons).tableExport({
//        formats: ['xls'],
//        exportButtons: false
//    });
// **************************************

var XLS = instance.CONSTANTS.FORMAT.XLS;
var CSV = instance.CONSTANTS.FORMAT.CSV;

//                                          // "id"  // format
var exportDataXLS = instance.getExportData()[tableId][XLS];
var exportDataCSV = instance.getExportData()[tableId][CSV];

// get filesize
var bytesXLS = instance.getFileSize(exportDataXLS.data, exportDataXLS.fileExtension);
var bytesCSV = instance.getFileSize(exportDataCSV.data, exportDataCSV.fileExtension);

console.log('filesize (XLS):', bytesXLS + 'B');
console.log('filesize (CSV):', bytesCSV + 'B');

var XLSbutton = document.getElementById('customXLSButton');
XLSbutton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    //                   // data             // mime                 // name                 // extension
    instance.export2file(exportDataXLS.data, exportDataXLS.mimeType, exportDataXLS.filename, exportDataXLS.fileExtension);
});

var CSVbutton = document.getElementById('customCSVButton');
CSVbutton.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    //                   // data             // mime                 // name                 // extension
    instance.export2file(exportDataCSV.data, exportDataCSV.mimeType, exportDataCSV.filename, exportDataCSV.fileExtension);
});
```

This is the website:

```
<div><button id=\"customXLSButton\">Export</button></div>

<table>
<th><td>K&ouml;rper</td><td>BMI</td></th>
</table>
```

Where can i set the encoding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you try this option:

```
charset: 'charset=Windows-1252',

var instance = new TableExport(ExportButtons, {
    formats: ['xls', 'csv'],
    exportButtons: false,
    charset: 'charset=yourencoding'
});
```